# Count the number of occurrences of each email address

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL workbench table called table_contacts, with the fields:

user_id and PrimaryEmail

I want to write a query that, for each row in the table will return:

User_id, PrimaryEmail and Number of occurrences of that email address in the table. So I want the following table to be returned:

[image]

I know I need to use a sub query. So far I have:

```
select user_id, PrimaryEmail, 
(select Count(PrimaryEmail) from table_contacts where PrimaryEmail = table_contacts.PrimaryEmail) 
from table_contacts
```

But this is returning the count of all email addresses in the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select user_id, PrimaryEmail, Count(PrimaryEmail)
from table_contacts
group by PrimaryEmail
```

in SQL tryit editor a similar query would be

```
SELECT customerid,count(country),country FROM [Customers] group by country
```

but in this case you receive only the count of each email (one row for each email). Other (better) solutions have been proposed if you want to list all the rows with the couunt added.

Comment: @djoosi has proposed another valid solution

Answer (score 3):

The solution of Simone and Grażynka will group by address, so you will lose some row each time the email address is more than one time.

To display all row with a count of same email, you can do :

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.PrimaryEmail, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_contacts t2 WHERE t2.PrimaryEmail = t1.PrimaryEmail) FROM table_contacts t1
```

Comment: isn't the purpose of the group by - count to do this without losing rows? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No, i think you can do this request with group by if you just want to display the number of each email address in the table. But here, Alex want to display each row and just add a column to count the email in the same table..

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
Select user_id, primaryemail, count(*)
 from table_contacts
group by user_id, primaryemail
```

Comment: why group by on user_d?

Comment: Cause I'm selecting it without an aggregate function.

Comment: thanks! I've fixed my solution too and upvoted yours.

Answer (score 2):

You need a group by, not a subquery

something like

```
select user_id, PrimaryEmail, Count(PrimaryEmail)
from table_contacts
group by PrimaryEmail
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
select t1.user_id, t1.PrimaryEmail, count(*) 
from table_contacts t1 
     join table_contacts t2 on t1.PrimaryEmail = t2.PrimaryEmail 
group by t1.user_id, t1.PrimaryEmail 
order by t1.user_id;
```